# Clearly something wrong with my hide/show column function

Tags: jquery

I have added a class to all of the td's associated with my table. I have created a checkbox  and use the following code to select the checkbox, take its value which is just a number, add that number to the word column and put it in a variable. I have a class for instance of, column3. I am using my code to build the name column3 using the value of the checkbox. I want to make it hide that specific class. When I alert the col value it gives me the right name. However when I try to execute the code the column does not hide. I don't know if it has something to do with how jQuery is reading my self created object. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Here is the code for the jQuery.

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('checked')){
        alert($(this).val());

        var col ='column' + $(this).val();
        col = '".' + col + '"'; 
        alert(col);
        $(col).hide();
    }
    else {
        $(col).show();
    }
```

Comment: As a side comment, if you're using the latest version of jQuery, I would highly recommend using `prop()` instead of `attr()`.

Comment: now that I am using a version of jquery 1.6 something

Comment: ha thats funny i just added that before u had that in

Comment: `col` is not defined in your `else`-branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        col = '.column' + $this.val();

    if ($this.attr('checked')){
        $(col).hide();
    }
    else {
        $(col).show();
    }
});
```

The main problem was that you were wrapping the class name with quotation marks, so your selector would have looked like this: `$('".column3"')` when it should look like this `$('.column3')`.

Also, you were declaring `col` inside the "if checked" control and attempting to utilize it within the else statement.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jzJeb/

You can't add the `"` to the variable `col` value.  You end up with '".column1"' instead of just '.column1' for example.  Also, the `col` variable is not in scope when you are trying to show the column.

Answer (score 0):

This is the one working, I think you have a problem there with double quotation in

```
col = '".' + col + '"';
```

I tried like this and this one works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("input:checkbox").click(function(){
     var col ='.column' + $(this).attr("value");
       if($(this).attr('checked')){
            $(col).hide();
       }
       else {
            $(col).show();
       }
     });
});
```